# i got TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

```
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-4,5,1)

y=(math.sqrt(math.cos(x)))*(math.cos(300*x))+(math.sqrt(abs(x))-0.7*(4-x*x)**0.1) 


plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I want to plot this function. It's simple, but I'm having trouble with this. When I run the program, it says:

```
File "funct.py", line 7, in <module>
    y=(math.sqrt(math.cos(x)))*(math.cos(300*x))+(math.sqrt(abs(x))-0.7*(4-x*x)**0.1) 
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalar
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the `numpy` versions of the functions, not the ones from `math` or `builtins`, can broadcast instead of processing a scalar argument. You want this:

```
y = (np.sqrt(np.cos(x)))*(np.cos(300*x))+(np.sqrt(np.abs(x))-0.7*(4-x*x)**0.1)
```

Granted, this has its own problem: `np.cos(x)` gives some negative values, which you attempt to square-root.

Comment: thanks aryamccarthy, you really help me

Comment: Is your question addressed? If so, you can help future users by marking the checkbox beside the correct answer. If not, what can be clarified?